# Mastermind Minimax algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, minimax, knuth

I am trying to implement Donald Knuth's algorithm for solving Mastermind, as detailed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Five-guess_algorithm

Most of my code is working, but I can't get the Minimax step to work (in the `get_guess` method of the `ComputerGuesser` class). I've already had a look on [Mastermind minimax algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298190/mastermind-minimax-algorithm) but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

## Feedback class

```
class Feedback(object):
    def __init__(self, number_in_correct_place, number_in_incorrect_place):
        self.number_in_correct_place = number_in_correct_place
        self.number_in_incorrect_place = number_in_incorrect_place

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.number_in_correct_place, self.number_in_incorrect_place).__str__()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.number_in_correct_place == other.number_in_correct_place and self.number_in_incorrect_place == other.number_in_incorrect_place

    def __hash__(self):
        prime1 = 31
        prime2 = 17
        return (prime1 * self.number_in_correct_place) + (prime2 * self.number_in_incorrect_place)
```

## Utility methods

```
def generate_all_possibilities(code_length, number_of_colours):
    return [p for p in itertools.product(range(1, number_of_colours + 1), repeat=code_length)]


def get_feedback(code, guess):
    assert len(guess) == len(code)

    number_in_correct_place = 0
    number_in_incorrect_place = 0
    matched = [False] * len(code)
    for i in range(len(code)):
        if guess[i] == code[i]:
            number_in_correct_place += 1
            matched[i] = True

    for i in range(len(code)):
        if guess[i] != code[i] and guess[i] in code:
            for j in range(len(code)):
                if guess[i] == code[j] and not matched[j]:
                    number_in_incorrect_place += 1
                    matched[j] = True
                    break

    return Feedback(number_in_correct_place, number_in_incorrect_place)


def filter_possibilities(possibilities, feedback, guess):
    return [p for p in possibilities if feedback == get_feedback(guess, p)]
```

## Computer guesser

```
from collections import Counter
from guesser import Guesser
from utils import generate_all_possibilities, filter_possibilities, get_feedback


class ComputerGuesser(Guesser):
    def __init__(self, code_length, number_of_colours):
        super(ComputerGuesser, self).__init__(code_length, number_of_colours)
        self.all_possibilities = generate_all_possibilities(code_length, number_of_colours)
        self.filtered_possibilities = generate_all_possibilities(code_length, number_of_colours)

    def alert_feedback(self, feedback, guess):
        self.filtered_possibilities = filter_possibilities(self.filtered_possibilities, feedback, guess)

    def get_guess(self):
        key = lambda g: max(Counter(get_feedback(g, c) for c in self.filtered_possibilities).values())
        guess = min(self.all_possibilities, key=key)
        return guess
```

Edit: Running the code (with some added print statements) produces the following:

```
Code: [3, 1, 4, 3]
12 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 2, 2) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 256
11 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 3, 4, 4) Feedback: (1, 2)
Number of possibilities left: 21
10 turns remaining
Guess: (3, 1, 4, 5) Feedback: (3, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 3
9 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 3) Feedback: (2, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
8 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 1) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
7 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 1) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
6 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 1) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
5 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 1) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
4 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 1) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
3 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 1) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
2 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 1) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
1 turns remaining
Guess: (1, 1, 1, 1) Feedback: (1, 0)
Number of possibilities left: 1
```

Comment: You really need to be more specific. "I can't get this code working" and placing (all?) your code here, looks a lot like 'solve this for me'. What is wrong with the guesser? What results are you getting and what is wrong with them?

Comment: @pyrocumulus , I've added some example output the question. I suspect the problem is either with the line `key = lambda g: max(Counter(get_feedback(g, c) for c in self.filtered_possibilities).values())` or `guess = min(self.all_possibilities, key=key)` (both in the `get_guess` method).